# sampling x, y coordinates from an equation of a line or curve

Tags: matlab

I'm new to matlab.  I'm trying to write a program where given an equation of a line or circle/curve I can get the set of x, y coordinates (preferably as a 2D array) that are spaced a certain equal distance apart, say every unit or half unit of line length or arc length.

For example I have a linear line that starts at (-2, 5), has a slope of -1/4,is 100 units long and I want the x, y coordinate every 1 unit down that line. Is there a function that does this or do I need to write the loops myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defined your function:

```
f = @(x) -x./4 + 4.5;
```

If you want x to be a 100 unit long array in steps of 1, you can declare it as:

```
x = -2:97;
```

If you want x to be a 100 unit long array from -2 to e.g. 50 (or any arbitrary end point) you get this with:

```
x = linspace(-2,50,100)
```

(100 points is default for linspace, so you don't actually need to write 100. You can use the parameter for any arbitrary number of points.)

Now your y array is:

```
y = f(x);
```

If you like, you could now make a matrix with all coordinates:

```
coordinates = [x',y']
```